# Seeking 19th century marriage record from Upper Silesia in Poland?

Tags: 19th-century, marriage-records, poland

I am looking for information on my great great grandparents who came from Upper selesia area in Poland. The names were Anthony Nanik, Hedwiga Wodarz and Mary Urbanik. My great grandfather Gregor Nanik who married in Jelowa Poland. I have been on several sites and cannot find much on the names. I would like to obtain birth certificates or marriage information. Gregor Nanik was born 9 Mar 1847 and Hedwiga wodarz was 24 Jul 1851.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I think that you should focus this question on finding a marriage record for Gregor and Hedwiga.  Finding their birth records could be two separate questions.  It is unclear how Mary Urbanik relates to them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that it is better to find local genealogist in Poland who knows the Polish language. And to make the order for getting documents from him. I believe that there are such. Maybe it is good idea to start from resources like http://genealogiapolska.pl/
Also online records may exists. Please refer to https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Poland_Online_Genealogy_Records
You may check them on your own.

Answer (score 1):

[Poczekalnia](http://poczekalnia.genealodzy.pl/pliki/) might have the records from the town. They are slowly adding more records online.

There is also a [project](http://www.geneteka.genealodzy.pl/index.php?op=gt&lang=pol&bdm=D&w=08op&rid=D&search_lastname=&search_name=&search_lastname2=&search_name2=&from_date=&to_date=&rpp1=&ordertable=) to index Polish records. I checked Opole but did not find any records; however, it might be something to bookmark to return to later.

Answer (score 1):

My Great grandmother Mary Lee Nanik wrote this down when she was 80 yrs. old.She says that she had a hard time reading but wrote it as she saw it.

She say Gregoire and Yadwiga (Hedwiga) were married in the Catholic Church in a village called Yellown (Jelowa) in upper Silesia, Germany (then Prussia) in Nov.1873

Answer (score 0):

From the 1930 US Census it appears that Gregor and Hedwig Nanick were living at Browerville, Todd, Minnesota, United States, and were born in Poland in about 1847 and about 1855 respectively.  They appear to have immigrated in 1886 and 1887 respectively so Gregor appears to have arrived in the US first and Hedwig followed.  Their ages at first (only?) marriage were 26 and 19 respectively which would suggest that they were married in Poland (or at least not in the US) in about 1873-1874.  They had both been naturalized so if you can find those records then perhaps they will shed light on precisely where and when they married.

> "United States Census, 1930," database with images, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X3DT-SYB : accessed 20
>   October 2017), Hedwig Nanik in household of Gregor A Nanik,
>   Browerville, Todd, Minnesota, United States; citing enumeration
>   district (ED) ED 5, sheet 8B, line 59, family 183, NARA microfilm
>   publication T626 (Washington D.C.: National Archives and Records
>   Administration, 2002), roll 1132; FHL microfilm 2,340,867.

Gregor also appears in the 1905 Minnesota State Census.

> Citing this Record "Minnesota State Census, 1905," database with
>   images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:SPQ6-5NH
>   : 3 August 2017), Gregas Nanick, Ward township, Todd, Minnesota;
>   citing p. 226, line 313, State Library and Records Service, St.Paul;
>   FHL microfilm 928,819.