# Seeking 1873 marriage record for Gregor Nanik from Upper Silesia?

Tags: marriage-records, poland, 1870s, silesia

Gregor was married in 1873 to Hedwiga Wodarz. His father was Anthony Nanik.
I heard were friends of the Hindenburgs and Gregor served in the Military.
During the war hid in the caves. He immigrated to America in 1885 by way of Bremen Germany. Hedwiga was born August 24 1851. Would like to know where to look for records of marriage, birth and military information.

Comment: Is this the Gregor Nanik that you are interested in?  "United States Census, 1930," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X3DT-SYY : accessed 12 June 2018), Gregor A Nanik, Browerville, Todd, Minnesota, United States; citing enumeration district (ED) ED 5, sheet 8B, line 58, family 183, NARA microfilm publication T626 (Washington D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, 2002), roll 1132; FHL microfilm 2,340,867.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  This looks like it may be a duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13463/19  I think that it would be helpful if your questions about marriage records, birth/baptism records and military records were asked as separate questions.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9392 which has much advice?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question could be improved by telling us the sources that you've already found.